French TV movie about contemporary slavery in Paris
I watched a few years ago a contemporary French TV movie ("téléfilm", a movie broadcasted on TV only) set in current times (there is basic Internet so I would say 2000-2010 time-frame). 
This is the story of a French family living in Paris who has a maid from a foreign country (Africa, maybe, or SE Asia ?). The son of that family, a pre-teenager, slowly realizes that she is almost a slave (sleeping in the kitchen, working extreme hours,...). 
He wants to do something but is met with a violent opposition of his grandmother (the mother of his father) who stands by her son and declares that he would never treat her maid badly (the grandmother lives on her own).
The boy finally finds on Internet a humanitarian organization who helps the maid to get free. The grandmother initially is furious against the boy but somehow discovers the truth and (I do not remember exactly) ends up slapping her son and (I think) helping the young maid in court. 
I do not remember any of the actors (they are French, except maybe for the maid). The movie is probably a low-key one (by blockbusters standards) but I would be glad to get the title and watch it again. 

Google "French actors" in images and find at least one that was in this show, that'll help!

@ringø: as mentioned in my email, I do not remember any. I barely recognize my kids so except if the actor/actress was super well-known I would not recognize his/her. Since this is a TV movie the actors will probably be less famous. Finally, if I knew an actor in that movie I would have gone though his filmography to identify the movie.
